# Static react app hosted on aws s3 not renders root but renders any other route

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, create-react-app, amazon-cloudfront

I have a react app hosted as a static website on aws s3, this app worked since some past versions but then i made some changes and the app crashed on the root, but if I go to another route the app is rendered also if I type a wrong route i am rendered to the route(as is coded the app) and now I can see it but if i refresh then the app is blank again. Going to devtools i noticed this:

**when opening the root route:**

the static folder from the build folder is not loaded and page not rendered

[image: opening root route just index file is shown]

**when opening another route or a incorrect one(loading the root):**

the static folder is loaded and the page rendered

[image: opening another route that is not root or a incorrect one to get redirected to root]

is important to note that on localhost is always rendered well, why could this happens on production? this s3 static website is server throw cloudfront and the direct static website link from s3 is rendered but the cloudfront one not so I think the problem starts here on cloudfront